# Russian equivalents of “not above doing anything to ...”

Tags: выражения

In conversation, I wanted to express the idea of "not above doing anything to do ..." and said:

> ... Впрочем он, я смотрю, **ничем не побрезгует** ради достижения собственных целей, какое уж там вести себя самоотверженно!

I'm wondering if my phrasing matches well with the English expression in terms of register, for one thing, and the use of "побрез**гать**" might not have been a better choice?

What is a commonly used phrasing for this in Russian?

Comment: **брезгать** is either an old or dialectal form, but in the present and future tenses they're sound almost identically anyway... their synonym **гнушаться** may also be used taking into account its higher register

Comment: thank you for sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your translation is pretty good.
There are a number of similar expressions, such as **"он может пойти на всё ради достижения собственных целей"**, but if we are talking about **"not above doing anything to do ..."**, more or less  literal option would be **"он может опуститься до чего угодно ради достижения собственных целей"**, but I personally like the option you use more.

Answer (score 3):

Не "брезгать", а "брезговать". -уе- should have warned you. Like требует - требовать.

> Ничем не побрезгует
>
> Ничем не погнушается
>
> Ничем не поступится
>
> **Ни перед чем не остановится**
>
> Что угодно сделает
>
> Пойдет на всё
>
> Родину (или мать) продаст

But not everything goes well with the second part of your sentence. That's why I like the variant you used, and for some others the second clause must be paraphrased.

Comment: The word "брезгать" sounds not very good to me too, but it's technically the correct word: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: Nevertheless, we don't use it commonly. I'd say it is outdated.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you on that. **"Брезговать"** is better.

Comment: брезгать follows the same pattern as падать, делать

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка but it's not the Infinitive of "брезгует". According to wiki, it брезгать - брезгает.

Comment: of course it's not, i never meant that, you may have misread the OP's question, because he only suggested **побрезгать** as an *alternative* verb (being aware that it's a *correct* form), and not as an infinitive of **побрезгует** as you may have thought